# how to store special characters in json column in mysql

Tags: sql, json, laravel

Im am trying to save some special characters in a json column of a table. but this is actually not working 
this is how it is stored

```
{"district":"\u099a\u09be\u0981\u09a6\u09aa\u09c1\u09b0",
"sub_district":"\u099a\u09be\u0981\u09a6\u09aa\u09c1\u09b0"}
```

i am storing my input values as below..i am using laravel

```
present = array('district'=>$request->district,'sub_district'=>$request->sub_districtce);

    $card->present_address = json_encode($present);
```

and while searching for a string in that json object, i am using a query below

```
$allowances = Card::SELECT('id','name','nid','village')
    ->where(DB::raw("json_extract((present_address), '$.district')"), চাদপুর)
    ->get();
```

can anybody help me on this situation where i can store special characters/unicodes in that json object.?

Comment: Show us the vlaue of `$request->district` and `$request->sub_districtce`

Comment: please share how it is supposed to look before it is getting stored

Comment: it has to be stores as below 
'district' => 'চাঁদপুর',
      'sub_district' => 'চাঁদপুর',

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly normal. As soon as you will do `json_decode()`, you will get back your expected values:

```
    array (
      'district' => 'চাঁদপুর',
      'sub_district' => 'চাঁদপুর',
    )
```

Comment: what if i want to perform a query in that particular column.?

Comment: if you want to perform queries, you need to store them in their own columns

Comment: hey hubert... 
        ->where(DB::raw("json_extract((present_address), '$.ward_no')"), 28)
this is the where condition of my query which was working fine when i have no no special characters.. as u are saying to use json_decode...how should i use that in my condition.?

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the code that you want me to look at?

Comment: have a look hubert

Comment: Your query should be working, MYSQL should properly convert back to your special characters, is it showing any error?